# Kivy - check if popup is currently showing (because Kivy Popup isn't really modal (back button/keyboard))

Tags: python, popup, widget, kivy

I bind to Window.on_key_down in my root widget to handle android's back button.

ModalView (and it's child Popup) are not REALLY modal, they don't handle the keyboard at all, hence the back button is also not handled.

If I inherit from Popup and do a bind to Window.on_key_down which returns True, then I can handle the back button from within my inheriting class. At this point I can either unbind in on_dismiss or delete the widget (can't seem to get deletion to work reliably, but that's not a separate question).

The problem is that this partitions out my handling of the back button across all my screens (I use a screen manager) rather than in my root widget. So I'm looking for a way to check, from my root widget, if ANY popups are currently open (preferably without iterating through the widget tree as won't scale too well). Please advise on the options I'm thinking off below as well as any other suggestions:-

## Option 1

One single popup widget initialized in the root widget, which all screens will modify/open() when necessary. This would necessitate binding/unbinding the buttons of that popup, of course. The root widget can then easily check this single object to see if its open or not.

## Option 2

Handle keyboard in a class inheriting from popup widget, and unbind the keyboard at the end. Problem of splitting back button handling to many files/screens, and building up of old popup widgets over long use of the app.

## Option 3

???

Comment: Had you considered maintaining some sort of root application level property which represented a list of all open popup windows?

Comment: I have (did something similar previously to keep track of text inputs with or without focus), but I don't see any advantages of that approach over option 1 because it would still tightly couple the child widgets to root, while distributing the code further out compared to a single pop-up. Benefit is lack of binding required, of course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are running an kivy application ([`kivy.app`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html)) you can do the following within your back button callback:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

if isinstance(App.get_running_app().root_window.children[0], Popup):
    App.get_running_app().root_window.children[0].dismiss()
```

The popup will prepend an object of kind `Popup` to the window object within its [`open()`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/modalview.py#L166) method (default behaviour of `add_widget()`, which assumes insertion index of 0).

In slightly more complex situations (multiple popups or using the `inspector` module), iterating through all children works as well.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

for widget in App.get_running_app().root_window.children:
    if isinstance(widget, Popup):
        widget.dismiss()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to have to test it out when I get the time. Actually I'm wanting to take a look at the Popup code to ensure that it actually does prepend. And also take a look at what happens with multiple ModalViews =)

Comment: So the `ModalView` code does add_widget() to the window, which defaults to adding at index = 0, so as long as no other widgets have been added to the Window your solution would work fine. Adding a note to that effect, and accepting your answer, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this answer is no longer valid, as further live testing on my app indicates that children[0] may not always be the popup. In particular when running the inspector module `python main.py -m inspector` it's always taking precedence. I think I will need to iterate through the children list to do this. Will have to see if multiple popups are always 'last in is lowest index'.

Comment: If you add another widget to the window-object after opening the popup, it won't be the first object. Iterating the childrens may work es well. I would expect that the order does not change but I have not tested it.

Comment: The inspector module is Kivy built-in, and it's not really added after, I think it hooks itself to always be the first child (makes sense due to what it does). Iterating through children does work, let me edit your answer and re-accept it.